# Using Omnipage 19 convert to MP3 functionality, can you utilize control sequences?

Tags: text-to-speech, control-characters

Basically; Omnipage can convert things like PDF's to MP3 Audio using a Text to Speech engine. The engine I think its using to do this is Realspeak Solo v4.0:

[image]

I want to use control sequences to control how the text is being read, however, all the control sequences I have tried thus far are not being recognized by the software.

For example I tried this:

```
\x1B\rate=10\ The rate is set to a low value. \x1B\rst\ Now it is reset to its default value.
```

and

```
<ESC>\vol=10\ The volume is set to a low value. <ESC>\rst\ Now it is reset to its default value.
```

Neither worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After dealing with Nuance; the parent company of Omnipage, it is fairly safe to assume that they reserve control sequences for those who are prepared to invest a bare minimum of $25,000 to get an Emerald License. Otherwise; none of their products support this, not even their SDK.

As an aside, I would recommend not doing any development with Nuance. They are horrid to deal with. For example; their documentation indicates that you can use control sequences with their HTTP 1.1x api, but not 1.0. The reason why this is a nuisance:

1. Only HTTP 1.0 is documented.
2. All their examples are old and unclear what version of the HTTP Framework they are working with.
3. They don't tell you anywhere that while control sequences work with 1.1x, they fundamentally will NOT WORK if you don't have an "Emerald License" that costs again, $25k
4. They don't even let you test control sequences in the developer sandbox.